# Android ouTouch shows actionbar and bottomtabs

Tags: android, android-tabs, touch-event

What i want is to build an app that reads very long text from database and display it into lot of pages. And i also wanted to have onTouchEvent i think for the First screen. And will be shown like this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTTnf.png. When its touched it will like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcpdc.png. Can you help me with this, i just wanted to know where should i start from here. Maybe some link which is just like this or something like this one, just something i can refer to and get started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use "SystemUiHider"

for example create new project in android studio , in "Add an Activity " Select FullScreen Activity and run  :)